# Is there a way to overwrite error counter in SLE4428 card?

Tags: android, smartcard, eeprom

I am reading and writing to SLE4428 card with ACR38 device and it's android sdk. I get error counter 7F before writing. Then after verifying PSC, the error counter at 1021 byte address becomes FF. But after disconnecting and reconnecting card, I found that error counter is still 7F.

Why is that and is there any way to overwrite error counter to FF so that it remains FF even after disconnecting and reconnecting?